# getChat doesn't return active_usernames Telegram Bots API

Tags: rest, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to get a list of all active users using getChat method.

Acording to the documentation the list is returned if we use this specific method:
`https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat`
`https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat`

But it doesn't work on my end:

[image: request in postman]